# Having issues with fields/permissions in Salesforce Sites (Accounts Related)

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Hey guys I really need help with setting up sites:

I have a visualforce page that I am setting up in sites and I have gone through the profile (guest sites user) and given them all the relevant access settings for the objects, visualforce pages & the apex classes.

My page render fine when I access it internally (through SALESFORCEURL/apex/page) but when I access it through the sites URL it has an issue rendering the fields.

Basically I have an account record which I prefil using an ID in the URL Parameter (this is all working and testing via the internal visualforce page). In the internal page it appears as a prefilled editable inputText box which I can edit and submit fine. In sites the fields appear as a non-editable outputLabel that of course I can not edit, and this is the entire purpose of my visualforce page.

Does anyone have a work around for this? Or at least a solid reason as to why it works in the internal visualforce page but not from sites?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @David, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)

Comment: @MarkPond thanks bud I posted my question over there too hopefully someone can help me :)